# Empty mongo db and EJS (Express blog app)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to get a placeholder working for if there are no blog posts on an EJS file...

If there are items in the database everything works fine, but I'm having trouble with getting an if else statement working. Here's what I've got:

```
<% if (typeof posts != undefined || posts.length >= 2) { for (var i = posts.length - 1; i > posts.length - 3; i--) {  %>
                            <a class="post-link" href="/posts/<%= posts[i]._id %>">
                            <div class="post-body">
                                    <div class="post">
                                        <div class="post__heading">
                                            <h2 class="heading-secondary"><%= posts[i].title %></h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="post__content">
                                            <p><%= posts[i].body.slice(0, 800) %>...</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="date">
                                            <span class="heading-secondary-date">
                                                    <%= posts[i].date %>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        <% } } else { %>
                            <h1>There is nothing here</h1>
                        <% } %>
```

I must be doing something wrong because EJS isn't recognising the if else statement.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,

Raph

Answer (score 0):

Try with this instead of else:

```
<%if(typeof posts == undefined){%><h1>There is nothing here</h1><%}%>
```